# attach a remote file to an email in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I know it is possible to send mail through oracle apex using apex mail with an attachment with the following code -

```
DECLARE
    l_id NUMBER;
BEGIN
    l_id := APEX_MAIL.SEND(
        p_to        => 'fred@flintstone.com',
        p_from      => 'barney@rubble.com',
        p_subj      => 'APEX_MAIL with attachment',
        p_body      => 'Please review the attachment.',
        p_body_html => '<b>Please</b> review the attachment');
    FOR c1 IN (SELECT filename, blob_content, mime_type 
        FROM APEX_APPLICATION_FILES
        WHERE ID IN (123,456)) LOOP

        APEX_MAIL.ADD_ATTACHMENT(
            p_mail_id    => l_id,
            p_attachment => c1.blob_content,
            p_filename   => c1.filename,
            p_mime_type  => c1.mime_type);
        END LOOP;
    COMMIT;
END;

 /
```

but ,I want to attach a file on the disk(OS) to a mail sent through oracle apex instead of blob content

```
        p_attachment => c1.blob_content,
```

i.e., i want to attach a file for example `D:\sample.pdf` as attachment in the mail.

I want to know if it is possible and if possible then how?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Can you clarify further what you mean with "remote file". You mention "D:\": is this file on a disk on the database or are you talking about a file stored on a user's PC?

Comment: I am talking about a file stored in the file system of the server containing the database. instead of storing as blob i want to store the files in the file system

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from my post [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3896343)

I sent the mail using the below method

```
DECLARE
    l_id NUMBER;
  l_bfile BFILE;   
  l_blob BLOB; 
   BEGIN

   DBMS_LOB.createtemporary(l_blob, TRUE); -- Initialize the BLOB. 

   l_bfile := BFILENAME('TEST', 'test.pdf'); 

   DBMS_LOB.fileopen(l_bfile, DBMS_LOB.file_readonly); 

    DBMS_LOB.loadfromfile(l_blob, l_bfile, DBMS_LOB.getlength(l_bfile)); 

    l_id := APEX_MAIL.SEND(
        p_to        => 'account@host.com',
        p_from      => 'account@host.com',
        p_subj      => 'APEX_MAIL with attachment',
        p_body      => 'Please review the attachment.',
        p_body_html => '<b>Please</b> review the attachment');



       APEX_MAIL.ADD_ATTACHMENT(
            p_mail_id    => l_id,
            p_attachment => l_blob,
            p_filename   => 'test.pdf',
            p_mime_type  => 'application/pdf');

   DBMS_LOB.fileclose(l_bfile); 

   DBMS_LOB.freetemporary(l_blob);


    COMMIT;
END;
```